# magento 1.9.3.7 - google Tag Manager

Tags: magento-1.9

I have got a problem with a gtm script. This line always appears in all of my cms-blocks: 

`<script src="https://googletagmanager.eu/gtm.js"></script>`

After removing this in the Database - the next day it was again included in all blcoks.

I've searched the entire files - didn't find anything near "googletagmanager" or "gtm.js"

Comment: If you have installed before a extension for that , try to disable it first, flush cache, remove the files.
If not:
Check if you have added this script in the Design Configurations.
Do a grep on the root files : **grep -irH "googletagmanager" .**

Comment: thanks for the hint. There is no extension - never implemented googletagmanager. Also did a grep on the root files - the only result was my remove command in the .mysql_history: update cms_block set content=replace(content,"<script src=\"https://googletagmanager.eu/gtm.js\"></script>","");

Comment: If you have external page cache enabled, be sure to flush that too.

Comment: external full page cache is disabled

Comment: great! thank you, we could see in the trigger as well and fixed.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139311)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was recently employed to remove this malware from a UK based magento website.

The domain is not actually a Google domain, it is malware, see here
https://www.hybrid-analysis.com/sample/c91d1e290fc46ede3930192c80ee1bb42d301e5d23dec47affc44a0a1cdea76f?environmentId=100

You have to go into your mysql database and look at the TRIGGERS, you'll see one that contains the malware. Then delete all the code snippets from your header, footer and static blocks.. the code should not return this time

Delete this entire trigger, then do a full security audit and change all passwords etc.

Comment: Hello Mark, thanks so much for the input - that solved my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear, and happy to help. I would also check your magento file and folder permissions as well as checking for any malicious backdoor files such as adminer.php

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack mostlty through adminer.php. In magento its inserted into the database as a trigger. The trigger fires after a checkout has been placed and will insert  in database (cms_block and core_config_data). Steps to clean:

1. login in adminer or phpmyadmin
2. sql query: SHOW triggers;
3. Delete the trigger from there: DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trigger.name
4. replace database with senr(https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/comment-page-36/) or you can import export sql file and replace it with editor.
5. remove adminer.php and senr if you used it

Answer (score 0):

I found mine in core_config_data - i searched in value for %googletagmanager%. 
Also in phpMyAdmin you can see all Triggers in the DB and you can edit them. I only had one Trigger and it was completely filled with "after-sales-order" commands which inserted the code in diffrent cms-blocks and footerblocks. Also i had the tag in every CMS-Block and CMS-Page